# Entity Framework precisa de Session e HttpContext?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, session, crud

Assisti alguns vídeos sobre `Entity` e vi duas versões diferentes, em uma primeira era algo simples e direto (acredito que a forma crua do Entity), onde ele apenas instanciava o contexto do banco e aplicada o add, segue o código:

```
using(sampleEntities ctx = new sampleEntities()){
client clt = new client();
clt.name = txtName.Text;
clt.phone = txtPhone.Text;
ctx.Add(clt);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Mas outro professor em outro vídeo faz algo diferente usando as camadas `DAL`, `BLL` e `UI`, dessa vez adicionando também uma *Session* que serviria para "isolar" cada operação de cada usuário no site, enquanto a primeira versão supostamente teria conflitos entre os tantos usuários que estariam fazendo uso de uma mesma conexão para várias operações simultaneamente, segue o exemplo:

```
public static sample01Entities Current
{
    get
    {
           if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SampleDbContext"] == null)
        {
            db = new sample01Entities();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SampleDbContext"] = db;
        }
        return db;

    }
}
```

E aqui na classe DALCity:

```
    public void Add(cidade c)
{
    SampleDbContext.Current.cidade.Add(c);
    SampleDbContext.Current.SaveChanges();
    SampleDbContext.Current.ChangeTracker.Entries<cidade>();
}
```

A questão é: é seguro usar a primeira forma para operações `CRUD` sem comprometer o código/site/segurança etc? Ou devo sempre usar o segundo exemplo com a Session para "individualizar" as operações e conexões?

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O uso de Session com o Entity Framework é, muito pelo contrário, desencorajado.

1) DbContext implementa o padrão Unit of Work. Isso significa que o objetivo dele é te ajudar a incluir e carregar suas entidades, modificá-las e então finalmente enviar todos esses comandos para a sua base. Classes que possuem esse tipo de comportamento não são feitos para terem um ciclo de vida longo dessa forma, na qual o objeto é criado como estático uma vez e usado para todas as demais requisições.

2) É normal que sessões sejam criadas e destruídas ao longo das suas requisições e que a sua aplicação seja reciclada de tempos em tempos. Em ambos os casos, usar um objeto estático com sessão pode trazer alguns cenários inesperados, como perda de informações e estados inválidos do seu objeto de Contexto.

3) Mesmo que você não caia em um cenário como o acima, caímos no problema do longo ciclo de vida. O objeto do Contexto guarda em um cache próprio todas as informações que são consultadas/modificadas ao longo do tempo (ele não tem nenhum tipo de Garbage Collector próprio), o que significa que você acaba com vários objetos desnecessários e um potencial gigantesco de memória sendo utilizada sem necessidade. Considerando que cada usuário teria um Contexto diferente, provavelmente grande parte dessa memória ainda teria informações duplicadas entre si. Se estivermos falando de um cenário de Session Inproc seria pior ainda, pois toda essa memória alocada ainda prejudicaria a capacidade do seu servidor Web de responder mais requisições.

4) DbContext não é Thread-safe. Isso significa que ele não é feito para ter seu uso compartilhado por múltiplas requisições simultâneas, pois você corre o risco de cair em casos de condições de corrida, entre outros problemas que podem te jogar em estados inválidos ou a fazer uso de informações desatualizadas ou diferentes do desejado.

Criar novas instâncias de contextos não é uma atividade tão demorada ou cara para ser processada. Em aplicações Web, é comum que seja utilizada uma instância por requisição ou por operação específica.

Existem diversos artigos pela internet a fora explicando como utilizar o contexto por requisição através de conteiners de injeção de dependência (Ninject, Unity, SimpleInjector, etc.). Porém se você não quiser utilizá-los, pode tentar mantê-los dentro do objeto HttpContext:

```
public static class RequestContext
{
    public static sampleEntities Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("EFContext"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("EFContext", new sampleEntities());
            }
            return HttpContext.Current.Items["EFContext"] as sampleEntities;
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var context = HttpContext.Current.Items["EFContext"] as sampleEntities;
     if (context != null)
         context.Dispose();
}
```

Seu exemplo de uso:

```
public void Add(cidade c)
{
    var context = RequestContext.Current;

    context.cidade.Add(c);
    context.SaveChanges();
    context.ChangeTracker.Entries<cidade>();
}
```

Acredito que o cenário com injeção de dependências poderia te oferecer um melhor controle, mas essa abordagem também funciona.

Recomenda a leitura de alguns artigos (em inglês) para melhor entendimento de como utilizar o contexto do Entity Framework adequadamente: [Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework 6: an in-depth guide](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/) [MSDN - Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu pra absorver bastante e iluminar meu caminho!